# Getting Permission Denied console message while executing OfficeItem.organizer.getAsync in Office365

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In office 365 (version 1803) locally installed outlook(desktop client).
We have added our plugin which appears in the side panel. It fetches some field information from desktop outlook using outlook API's. It requires information about these 5 field properties from desktop outlook: "subject", "itemId", "organizer", "requiredAttendees", "optionalAttendees"

We use the getAsync API for this in compose mode of Appointment to fetch these values.

Example:

1. In case of subject we get correct response in console.

   ```
   window.Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync(function(res){console.log(res)});
   ```

> output: `{status:"succeeded", value: "appointment1"}`

2. In case of organizer

   ```
   window.Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer.getAsync(function(res){console.log(res)});
   ```

> output : **Permission Denied**

Please see the attached image for the console error message.

Notes: 
The same flow works fine in Outlook Web APP (OWA) in Internet Explorer browser.

We tried the above scenario in create and update flows from native outlook.

Does anyone knows the reason of this issue?
What can I do to resolve this issue in my locally installed outlook client?

[image: console screenshot]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>69833250-ebab-4f58-8606-59df2b358121</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Oracle</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Engagement Cloud"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com"/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com/</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html"/>
                <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read"/>
    </Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
                      xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultRead">
                            <Group id="oscReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscReadButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultCompose">
                            <Group id="oscComposeGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscComposeButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptRead">
                            <Group id="oscApptReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptReadButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptCompose">
                            <Group id="oscApptComposeGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptComposeButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_16.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_32.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="residOscHomeUrl" DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html"/>
                <bt:Url id="residOscHomeEditUrl" DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement Cloud"/>
                <bt:String id="buttonLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement Cloud"/>
                <bt:String id="superTipTitle" DefaultValue="fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupTooltip" DefaultValue="Oracle Engagement Cloud actions"/>
                <bt:String id="buttonTooltip" DefaultValue="Launches Oracle Engagement Cloud Application"/>
                <bt:String id="superTipDescription" DefaultValue="Launches Oracle Engagement Cloud Application"/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
                          xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultRead">
                                <Group id="oscReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscReadButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultCompose">
                                <Group id="oscComposeGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscComposeButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptRead">
                                <Group id="oscApptReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptReadButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptCompose">
                                <Group id="oscApptComposeGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptComposeButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Images>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_16x16"
                              DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_16.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_32x32"
                              DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_32.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_80x80"
                              DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
                </bt:Images>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <bt:Url id="residOscHomeUrl"
                            DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html"/>
                    <bt:Url id="residOscHomeEditUrl"
                            DefaultValue="https://fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com/crmUI/osc365/web/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
                </bt:Urls>
                <bt:ShortStrings>
                    <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement Cloud"/>
                    <bt:String id="buttonLabel" DefaultValue="Engagement Cloud"/>
                    <bt:String id="superTipTitle" DefaultValue="fuscdrmsmc151-fa-ext.us.oracle.com"/>
                </bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:LongStrings>
                    <bt:String id="groupTooltip" DefaultValue="Oracle Engagement Cloud actions"/>
                    <bt:String id="buttonTooltip" DefaultValue="Launches Oracle Engagement Cloud Application"/>
                    <bt:String id="superTipDescription" DefaultValue="Launches Oracle Engagement Cloud Application"/>
                </bt:LongStrings>
            </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: The organizer.getAsync API was implemented in [API requirement set 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/outlook-requirement-set-1.7). It's possible that it's not available in version 1803 of Outlook desktop. Can you check by running `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", 1.7)`? [isSetSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#use-runtime-checks-in-your-javascript-code) will indicate whether the client implements that requirement set.

Comment: I have added the manifest file. 

Also, if getAsync was not supported it should throw an error like "unable to get property 'getAsync' of undefined or null reference". Instead it is throwing Permission denied,

Answer (score 1):

Which permissions did you specify in the manifest?

Outlook add-ins specify the required permission level in their manifest. The available levels are `Restricted`, `ReadItem`, `ReadWriteItem`, or `ReadWriteMailbox`. These levels of permissions are cumulative: `Restricted` is the lowest level, and each higher level includes the permissions of all the lower levels. `ReadWriteMailbox` includes all the supported permissions.

The `Restricted` permission is the most basic level of permission. Specify `Restricted` in the `Permissions` element in the manifest to request this permission. Outlook assigns this permission to a mail add-in by default if the add-in does not request a specific permission in its manifest.

Attempting to access members such as subject or organizer will return null and result in an error message which states that Outlook requires the mail add-in to have elevated permission. You must request at least the `ReadItem` permission.

Comment: We deploy our add-in through Office Admin center for all users.

In our case, we specify the following permissions:

Read and write user calendars.

Read and write user contacts.

Create, read, update, and delete user tasks.

Create, read, update, and delete all tasks a user has access to.

Read and write user mail.

Read and write user mailbox settings.

Is there any difference between permission issued to OWA (outlook web app ) and locally installed outlook?

As we have seen this working in OWA mode.

Comment: Also, the add-in is deployed by an admin user and the issue is not seen in his machine, but for other users we are able to see this issue in desktop client.

Comment: It is hard to discuss any issues if we don't see the actual manifest file.

Comment: To clarify, please note that the [Permissions element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests#permissions) in the add-in manifest is separate from other permissions.

Comment: we have a ReadWriteItem permission.

Answer (score 0):

The organizer.getAsync API is not implemented in version 1803. I recommend checking the requirement set via `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", 1.7)` before calling the API. This will allow you to know if the requirement set is supported by your client version before using the API.

Comment: In 1808
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", 1.7) is false.

In 1803
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", 1.7) is also false.

But
organizer.getAsync is giving permission denied error in 1803 but not in 1808.

Can someone please specify the exact build number (outlook) from where the organizer.getAsync is supported?